# Run function after $.each inside a setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kindoff confused, I have a setTimeout() which has a $.each function to animate each slider every 5 seconds. ( this happens because of the other setTimeout() inside the $.each function.

> Now i'm wondering how I can run my **populateGraph()** function after
>   the setTimeout and the $.each are completed, I tried the following but
>   it runs at the same time

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);
        }, 500 + (500 * i));
    });
    populateGraph();
}, 500);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You call `populateGraph()` after your **last** setTimeout call, the trick is, knowing which one is your last:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var currentCount = data.length;
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);

            //decrease currentCount by one
            currentCount--;

            //if currentCount is at 0, then we know we've completed the last setTimeout
            if(!currentCount) {
              populateGraph();
            }
        }, 500 + (500 * i));
    });

}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var d= $.Deferred();
    var c=data.length;
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);

         if (i+1==c)   d.resolve();
        }, 500 + (500 * i));
    });

    d.done(function () {
        populateGraph();
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: What is $.deffered() ?

Comment: It is less jumpy that's for sure. Looking into the deferred

Comment: @Notflip - for full reference, there's no difference in calling `populateGraph()` instead of `d.resolve()` in this answer. It is certainly not faster/less jumpy to use `$.Deferred()`

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need use [`$.Deferred()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/), like so

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        len = data.length;

    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);

            if (i + 1 === len) {
               deferred.resolve();
            }
        }, 500 + (500 * i));
    });

    deferred.done(function () {
        populateGraph();
    });
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just schedule it 500ms after the last one?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);
        }, 500 * i);
    });
    setTimeout(populateGraph, 500 * data.length);
}, 500);
```

Comment: This is very clever! Would never of thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: @Notflip **No !!!**. there can be a GAP between execution times and calculated times !

Comment: @RoyiNamir it doesn't really matter if it's 500 or 550 :) It was important that the populateGraph() function is run after the loops were completed

Comment: @Notflip if you want to see jumps in the end of animation - be my guest. you are a programmer. do things right. not by estimations

Comment: I'll try your approach

Comment: @RoyiNamir: why would this cause jumps? We're already scheduling all the other animations with absolute time, so what difference will this make?

Comment: @Eric The upper part might take LONGER than the lower part ( lower code ) . now -an  extensive `populateGraph` function might hurt performance of a slieder which uses animation. again - it might. no matter how you look at it - it will never be the exact same time. and besides - this is (partially) what promises/deferreds are for

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Hang on, I think we're arguing about different things here - I call `populateGraph()` at least 500ms after the last slider update, whereas your code calls it simultaneously. My guess is that that is incorrect behaviour, since that leaves no time for the last slider to animate

Answer (score 0):

Seems that u need an emitter to help u out...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var emitter = new SuperEmitter(),//Create new super emitter
        emittors = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        emittors.push(v.id);//Collect all emittors that populateGraph() should wait
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);
            emitter.emit(v.id);//Emit emittor when one job is done
        }, 500 + (500 * i));
    });
    emitter.on(emittors,function(){
        populateGraph();
    });//Set event job after all the jobs are done
}, 500);
```

and here's my SuperEmitter constructor:

```
// Super Emitter
/**
 * Create a super emitter
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {String} name - The name of the emitter.
 * @author Maplemx(Maplemx@gmail.com)
 */
function SuperEmitter(name){
    var waitors = [],
        emittors = {};

    function tryEmittor(emittor,data){
        if (emittors[emittor]){
            data = mergeObjects(emittors[emittor],data);
        }
        for (var i = 0;i < waitors.length;i++){
            if (waitors[i]){
                var emittorIndex = waitors[i].wait.indexOf(emittor);
                if (emittorIndex > -1){
                    waitors[i].wait.splice(emittorIndex,1);
                    waitors[i].data = mergeObjects(waitors[i].data,data);
                }
                if (waitors[i].wait.length === 0){
                    waitors[i].func(waitors[i].data);
                    waitors[i] = undefined;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function tryWaitors(waitorId){
        if (waitors[waitorId]){
            for (var emittor in emittors){
                var emittorIndex = waitors[waitorId].wait.indexOf(emittor);
                if (emittorIndex > -1){
                    waitors[waitorId].wait.splice(emittorIndex,1);
                    waitors[waitorId].data = mergeObjects(waitors[waitorId].data,emittors[emittor]);
                }
                if (waitors[waitorId].wait.length === 0){
                    waitors[waitorId].func(waitors[waitorId].data);
                    waitors[waitorId] = undefined;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set new function into wait list
     * 
     * @public
     * @param {Array|*} emittors - The emittor(s) that the function wait for.(If emittor is not an Array, will turn it to an Array)
     * @param {Function} func - The function todo when emittor is sent.
     * @param {Object} [data] - The data want to send to the function.
     */
    this.on = function on(emittors,func,data){
        if (!(emittors instanceof Array)){emittors = [emittors];}
        var waitorId = waitors.push({
            wait: emittors,
            func: func,
            data: data,
        }) - 1;
        tryWaitors(waitorId);
    }

    /**
     * Send an emittor
     *
     * @public
     * @param {*} emittor - The emittor to be sent.
     * @param {Object} [data] - The data want to send to the functions which are waiting for the emittor.(The data here have higher priority than the data given when functions are put into wait list.)
     * @param {Boolean} [stay=true] - Tell if you want the emittor stay in memory, so that functions which are put into wait list later than emittor which are sent can also be activated by those emittor. If "stay" is true, you have to "unemit" the emittor manual.
     */
    this.emit = function emit(emittor,data,stay){
        if (typeof(stay) === 'undefined'){stay = true;}
        if (stay){
            emittors[emittor] = data;
        }
        tryEmittor(emittor,data);
    }

    /**
     * Erase an emittor (If "stay" is set false when emittor is sent, you don't need to erase it, because the emittor was not saved in memory)
     *
     * @public
     * @param {*} emittor - The emittor to be erased.
     */
    this.unemit = function unemit(emittor){
        if (emittors[emittor]){
            delete emittors[emittor];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wowie! I'll have to read that one slowly! Never heard of that approach :)

Comment: @Notflip yeah, the problem u post was also a problem trouble me when doing async programming... so i found this way to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [`Q` promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library here:

```
var promise = Q();
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    // since we construct this out of a .then callback, it's relative
    // to when this setup loop ran, not to the previous iteration
    var delay_until = Q.delay(500*i);

    // add to the promise chain
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return delay_until;
    }).then(function() {
        $(".slider#" + v.id).slider("value", globalcoachscores[i]);
    });
});
promise.then(populateGraph);
```

By setting up the delay's as I've done here, you get the best of both worlds:

- If something causes the page to lag, it'll catch up, rather than adding to the total animation time
- The order of animations is still guaranteed to be correct, due to the chain having to execute in order